# Synchronize Spark tasks

Tags: synchronization, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a strange behaviour in my Spark process which does as following :

1. read a reference file, load it as a `map M` and broadcast the map
2. read a second file and transform it getting `M` values

The problem is that the call to `M` for transformation is done BEFORE the broadcast is finished, and then it does not works as expected, because `M` is empty at this time.

My question is : How can I tell Spark to wait the loading and the broadcasting of an object before using it ?

Note : I've checked the call times and the calls are really not synchronized. Then, M is really correctly loaded.

The reference file loading :

```
  object RefObjectUtil extends java.io.Serializable {

  var map = Map[String, RefObject]()

  def loadAndBroadcast(inputPath: String, sc: SparkContext) = {
    val data = read(inputPath, sc).collect

    val i = data.iterator
    while (i.hasNext) {
      val a = i.next
      map.put(a.getValue.toString, a)
    }
    sc.broadcast(map)
  }

  @throws(classOf[RefObject])
  def get(key: String): RefObject= {
    isLoaded()
    map.getOrElse(key, null)
  }


  private def isLoaded(): Unit = {
    if(map.isEmpty) {
      throw new RefObjectException("file has not been loaded. Add it into path argument of your job")
    }
  }
```

Then the call :

```
 def run() {
       RefObjectUtil.loadAndBroadcast(inputPath, sc)
       val data = read(inputToTransformPath, sc)
       transform(data)  //called without waiting end of refObject loading 
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the transform(data) code. The load looks good to me...other than the fact that you aren't saving the broadcast variable...that is possibly your problem.  But, I need the code to be sure.

Comment: In fact, I just call something like `data.map( x => RefObjectUtil,get(x.key))`. What do you mean by saving the broadcast variable ? Do you think I should return the map from loadAndBroadcast and send it in input of read(inputToTransformPath, sc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the code   on the question does not work is not related to synchronization of processes. The code is probably correctly executed in the driver, but `RefObjectUtil` is a singleton object and it will be initialized again in each executor when referenced. At that point, `var map = Map[String, RefObject]()` gets initialized and will contain no data.

It looks like there are two Spark data sharing techniques ill-combined in one program.
Either we use the 'singleton object' pattern to hold data on each executor or we assemble the data in the driver and use broadcast to send it to the executors.

The 'singleton object' pattern is better suited to handle stateful resources like DB connections, which doesn't seem to be the case here. The broadcast variable would be the better choice.

Let's try to illustrate the use with an example:

*inspired by* the code in the question, this code loads some data, creates a map out of it and broadcasts it. The map is then used to resolve/translate a larger dataset. Note how the content of the broadcast variable is accessed within the closure using `broadcastVar.value`.

```
// get data into map form
val dataMap =  val data = read(inputPath, sc).map{elem => (a.getValue.toString, a)}.collectAsMap
// broadcast the data
val broadcastMap = sc.broadcast(dataMap)

val dataToProcessRDD = ???
dataToProcessRDD.flatMap{item =>
    broadcastMap.value.get(item) //broadcastMap.value => returns the wrapped map instance
}
```